# Table Diagram and Access File of Contact Database for Church

Tags: ms-access, database-diagrams

[image: Image of Tale diagram for church contact database]I have volunteered to design and develop an MS Access database for contacts at my local church in Jamaica, which has no budget to hire a database expert. I have attempted to design a database for the contacts, based on some requirements that I gleaned from the church leadership and administrators.

The church really wants to have a central place to store records on members, which they can delete/archive when members die or go away. They also wish to maintain records on marriages and anniversaries and emergency contacts. So I decided that the best approach is to focus on developing a contact database, that would include members, emergency contacts, non-member spouses of members, and other contacts that may be of service to the church and in turn the community served by the church.

Please help me to design a useful database by reviewing the table diagram attached. Any assistance would be useful.

Kind regards,
Kerry-Ann

Comment: please post the image directly by editing yourquestion and then select the picture button, for your side some has to login in.

Answer (score 0):

The design looks OK to me, though I wouldn't store phone numbers as `INTEGER`s, because in reality they are character sequences.

Since you want to track marriages of *members*, may be that should the parent for `marriages`, and not `contacts`.

If a member passes away, you may still want to maintain his/her record with a flag, instead of deleting it. This will preserve marriage and reference records, as well as emergency contacts. To accommodate that you'd want to add the membership end date and the termination reason attributes.

Comment: Thank you mustaccio. This has been sp helpful.

Comment: To your statement: "Since you want to track marriages of members, may be that should the the parent for marriages, and not contacts." On reflection, the reason why I am making Contacts parent is because there are church members who are married to non-members. We still would want to store the non-member spouse as a contact. Then, we can query which contact is an actual member.